# How to handle inter-process communication between TLM FIFOs that may or may not be written to this timestep

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want a UVM component that has two input TLM FIFOs and one output AP. For the two inputs, one receives packets that build state, and the other receives packets for querying the state that was previously built. The output AP broadcasts the state that the input AF requested. Below is a simple example with modeling a cache (new, build, etc. are ignored for brevity).

```
class cache_model extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(cache_model)

  // The two TLM FIFO inputs
  uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo#(cache_write_pkt_t) write_af;
  uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo#(tag_t) read_query_req_af;
  
  // The query response output
  uvm_analysis_port#(data_t) read_query_rsp_ap;

  // The internal state being modeled
  data_t cache[tag_t];

  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.run_phase(phase);
    fork
      forever process_writes();
      forever process_queries();
    join_none
  endtask

  protected task process_writes();
    cache_write_pkt_t pkt;
    write_af.get(pkt);
    // Converts the pkt to a tag and data and writes the cache
  endtask

  protected task process_queries();
    tag_t tag;
    read_query_req_af.get(tag);
    read_query_rsp_ap.write(cache[tag]);
  endtask
endclass
```

The problem I'm facing is the order of execution between the two `process_` tasks I've created. If there is both a write and a read to the cache in the same simulation timestep, I want the write to be processed first and then the read (I want the read to get the most recently written data). But it's entirely possible that the packets are pushed to the AFs in a different order.

I naively tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work because the `write_af` could not have been pushed to when `process_queries` begins executing, but it *will* get pushed to later in the simulation timestep:

```
event process_writes_done;

protected task process_writes();
  cache_write_pkt_t pkt;
  write_af.get(pkt);
  // Converts the pkt to a tag and data and writes the cache
  ->process_writes_done;
endtask

protected task process_queries();
  tag_t tag;
  read_query_req_af.get(tag);
  if (!write_af.is_empty()) begin
    wait(process_writes_done.triggered());
  end
  read_query_rsp_ap.write(cache[tag]);
endtask
```

In general, this can be extrapolated to any number of dependencies between forked processes that are waiting on TLM FIFOs.

This is the kind of scenario where people add `#0` to force ordering but I know that's not a good idea. So how can I guarantee process ordering in this scenario? Or is there a better methodology to follow when having a component waiting on many possibly-dependent FIFO packets?

Comment: We need a little bit more information. The way you show your code, the two forked `forever` processes are infinite 0-delay loops. There needs to be at least some delay or event control that keep it from being hung in a zero delay loop.

Comment: You want something like "execute some code at the end of the time slice", where you know that any transactions you may have have already been collected. This isn't possible natively, so you'll need something like `#0` or `uvm_wait_nba_region`, unfortunately.

Comment: @dave_59 The blocking event for each task is the call to `.get()`. These shouldn't be 0-delay loops.

Comment: `get()` does not necessarily block in all cases. But if in your case you can guarantee that is always does, then I can respond assuming that. (when I get the chance)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *write* to be processed before the *read* you should delay the *read*. Normally you could use a non-blocking assignment(NBA) to prevent race conditions, But the UVM TLM ports were not set up to do that. And you are correct in thinking inserting `#0` delays are a bad idea—they have a way of accumulating `#0 #0` and just postponing the race conditions.

UVM does have global task `uvm_wait_nba_region` that blocks for one iteration of the active/NBA events. You can put that in front of the `read_query_req_af.write()` in your monitor, or you can put it front of the `read_query_rsp_ap.write()` in your `process_queries()` task.

If you want to generalize this for one or more input analysis fifo's, we need to assume all of the input analysis fifos are written to synchronized to the same clock event in the *same* timestep. Otherwise you have a lot more explaining to do.

Then you can still have a process for each input fifo, but then you need an extra output process that executes after the single NBA region and looks as which input fifos received a transaction and handles the required ordering you need.

```
event evict, write, read;

// declarations for transactions e,w,r 
// but outside the task so they can be shared
epkt e;
cache_write_pkt_t w;
tag_t r;

task process_evict();
   evict_af.get(e);
   ->>evict; //NBA event trigger
endtask
task process_write();
   write_af.get(w);
   ->>write;
endtask
task process_read();
   read_af.get(r);
   ->>read;
endtask
task process_output();
   @(evict or write or read)
   if (evict.triggered) begin
     // stuff you need to do if there was an evict
   end
   if (write.triggered) begin
     // stuff you need to do if there was an write
   end
   if (read.triggered) begin
     // stuff you need to do if there was an read

     read_query_rsp_ap.write(cache[tag]);
   end
endtask
```

Comment: How can this be extrapolated to race conditions between more than two tasks?  Say I add a new AF and a new task `process_evictions`, and that I always want to enforce the ordering evict, write, read. Wouldn't putting a `uvm_wait_for_nba_region` in both the write and read tasks to ensure they execute after the evict task still lead to a race condition between the write and read tasks?

Comment: @Sean update my answer. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit it with more information, or maybe ask an entirely new question.

Comment: Thanks Dave. This is useful. And the assumptions you stated are correctly the assumptions I made.